# 16 segment display datasheet interpretation

Tags: datasheet, display

I'm looking at the [datasheet for Kingbright PSA08-12EWA](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1385/0900766b81385066.pdf).

There appears to be two voltage inputs and no DP connection. Am I mistaken? If not, why would they do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There indeed are two connections to the common anode and there is no decimal point LED fitted.

They would do that because that's what their major customers want (perhaps it is compatible with a previous design by another company).

The decimal point light pipe is in the molding because molds are expensive and it costs almost nothing to provide for it. They can make a different internal PCB if they want to provide the decimal point LED.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the PSA08-11SRWA does have a decimal point ([datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/216/PSA05-11SRWA-53569.pdf).

It does seem unusual they would do two versions.

Comment: These are different parts, and they do have different part numbers. What is unusual?